# Android code won't run

Tags: android

please don't scream on me, when I run the following code, which is used to calculate area of rectangle but app keeps crashing

*The app code:*

```
package com.example.xxxxxxx.reccalc;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
EditText widthField, lenghtField;
TextView areaResultView, perimetrResultView ;
Double lenght, width, areaResult, perimetrResult;

String s_areaResult =  String.valueOf(areaResult);
String s_perimetrResult =  String.valueOf(perimetrResult);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    widthField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.widthField);
    lenghtField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.lenghtField);
    areaResultView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.areaResultView);
    perimetrResultView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.perimetrResultView);

     lenght = Double.parseDouble(lenghtField.getText().toString());
    width = Double.parseDouble(widthField.getText().toString());



    areaResult = lenght * width;
    perimetrResult = (lenght * 2) + (width * 2);

    areaResultView.setText(s_areaResult);
    perimetrResultView.setText(s_perimetrResult);





}
}
```

Error code

    02-28 17:25:21.264 11178-11178/? I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni 
    (already on)
    02-28 17:25:21.265 11178-11178/? W/art: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using 
    defaults: x86
    02-28 17:25:21.539 11178-11178/com.example.xxxxxxxx.rectanglecalculator 
    W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: 
    /data/app/com.example.xxxxxxxx.rectanglecalculator-1/lib/x86
    02-28 17:25:21.575 11178-11178/com.example.xxxxxxxx.rectanglecalculator 
    I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
    02-28 17:25:22.010 11178-11178/com.example.xxxxxxxx.rectanglecalculator 
    W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter

android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
02-28 08:26:00.225 11178-11178/com.example.xxxxxxxx.rectanglecalculator D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
02-28 08:26:00.226 11178-11178/com.example.xxxxxxxx.rectanglecalculator E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                        Process: com.example.xxxxxxxx.rectanglecalculator, PID: 11178
                                                                                        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.xxxxxxxx.rectanglecalculator/com.example.xxxxxxxx.rectanglecalculator.MainActivity}: java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String
                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665)
                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
                                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
                                                                                         Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String
                                                                                            at java.lang.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1071)
                                                                                            at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:547)
                                                                                            at com.example.xxxxxxxx.rectanglecalculator.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:27)
                                                                                            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679)
                                                                                            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618)
                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726) 
                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477) 
                                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
                                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
                                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)

Comment: Hi! The error message you have posted is not the root cause of the error. Go to LogCat and turn off filters to try and find the real stacktrace/error message

Comment: According to the code done, when you are setting the value to the "lenght" it is setting to empty for the first time and when you are doing Double.parseDouble it is giving you crash

Comment: Please don't vandalize your posts.

Answer (score 1):

**lenghtField** and **widthField** are empty.
**`Double.parseDouble(emptystring)`** will be an error.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help you to solve the problem. Just Try the following steps..

- Go to AVD Manager
- Edit your AVD
- Uncheck 'Use Host GPU'option. OR change 'Graphics' option to Software- GLES 2.0
- Click Finish (Save).
- Then Start AVD again

Answer (score -1):

@Sergey You need to use Exception ,Use this code Its Working Fine..

Comment: Just declare your length and width  or calculate after button click so what ever value will be in edit text according to that it will calculate and take as "s_perimetrResult =  String.valueOf(perimetrResult); after "perimetrResult = (lenght * 2) + (width * 2);" . what is your case?